# Customizing portal's navigation bar

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I want to customize the navigation bar in my theme. I searched for the CSS file that styles the navigation bar in the css directory but I couldn't find it.

In the `nagivation.vm` file, the navigation is declared as follows:

```
<nav class="$nav_css_class" id="navigation">
```

and using firebug I found out that the class is

`sort-pages modify-pages`.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css file is called `css/navigation.css`. However, best practice is to do all modifications in `_diffs/css/custom.css` - this file is loaded last and all settings in there will override those in navigation.css and any other files. As a side effect, you'll have all of your settings neatly separated from Liferay's and are in a better position during updates.

custom.css is supposed to be empty in all themes that are meant for extension. If you start with the classic theme, you'll see that custom.css in there is not empty - this means, that the classic theme is not meant to be extended. Technically you can still do so of course, but Liferay might change this theme without notice in future versions and you'll end up upgrading then.